# He's been granted a special treatment

Tags: idiom-requests

If anyone is applying double standards, is there an idiomatic but elegant way to complain?

I suppose that "*He's been granted a special treatment*" is basically correct, but I have a feeling it's not exactly what a native speaker would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the normal way a U.S. English speaker would express the idea you have in mind is with this phrase:

> He gets [or *He's getting*] special treatment.

or this one:

> He receives [or *He's receiving*] preferential treatment.

Both sentences emphasize ongoing nature of the special treatment. If the special favor were a one-time-only thing, I would expect the wording to be be something more along the lines of

> He got special treatment [from whoever].

or

> He got a special break [from whoever].

In any case, you wouldn't use an indefinite article before *treatment*, because that would make it sound as though the person is receiving some type of special therapy or medication. And I wouldn't use *granted* because that suggests a kind of official stamp of favoritism that management is exceedingly unlikely to memorialize as such:

> We hereby grant Worker X's request for special treatment.

If the special treatment occurs as the result of an official request by Worker X, the wording of the approval is likely to be put in less jealousy-inducing terms:

> Because Worker X has a 250-mile commute, management has decided to permit him to work at home on Wednesdays.